# Android async task compiler error

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My async method is giving compiler error.This is my code:

```
private void registerInBackground() {
    new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {

        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

For line 2 I am getting this error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The type new AsyncTask(){} must implement the inherited abstract method AsyncTask.doInBackground(Object...)
    - Type safety: The method execute(Object...) belongs to the raw type AsyncTask. References to generic type AsyncTask<Params,Progress,Result> should be 
     parameterized
    - AsyncTask is a raw type. References to generic type AsyncTask<Params,Progress,Result> should be parameterized
```

For line 4 I am getting this error:

```
The method doInBackground(Void...) of type new AsyncTask(){} must override or implement a supertype method
```

How can I fix them ? What is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the generic class types in the `AsyncTask` constructor:

```
private void registerDoInBackground() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {

        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask is a parameterized class, since you do not specify the parameters, the compiler assumes you meant to use the Object type as parameter. You are using Void... as parameter of doInBackground, you should in this case use Object[] or Object... instead.

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
    return null;
}
```